# Using CMake to compile Assimp on Windows 10

Tags: cmake, assimp

I am attempting to use assimp for model importing in openGL. However, when building `assimp 4.1.0`, I get this:

```
15>-- Install configuration: "Debug"
15>CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:36 (file):
15>  file cannot create directory: C:/Program Files
15>  (x86)/Assimp/lib/cmake/assimp-4.1.  Maybe need administrative privileges.
```

I should have administrative privileges, but I am not entirely sure. If not, how would I update this. If this is not the case, what would another course of action be? My project and assimp both are under `Debug` as well as `Win32` (this gave a prior error, so I changed that).

Thank you.

Comment: ***15>  file cannot create directory: C:/Program Files
15>  (x86)/Assimp/lib/cmake/assimp-4.1.  Maybe need administrative privileges.*** The message is correct. You need UAC elevation to write to the `C:\Program Files` folder on a windows Vista and above.

Comment: Did you try running Visual Studio as [administrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/user-permissions-and-visual-studio?view=vs-2019#run-visual-studio-as-an-administrator)?

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/453249/is-uac-preventing-write-access-to-programs-folder

Comment: If you set `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` to something like `C:/Users/myaccount/Assimp` then there should be no need to run the install as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying another way which @Daniel Schepler said, install other places and then set the PATH to the prefix path in environment:

Example on my `cmake` and `build` and `install`: [in Window10]

```bash
# cmake
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=D:\Users\installpkg\bin -S . -B build -G "MinGW Makefiles"

# build and install
cmake --build build --target install
```

Explain a little bit:

1. `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=D:\Users\installpkg\bin` This flag is set the install path to `=` path
2. `-G "MinGW Makefiles"` is for MinGW to make.

Then you will see the result [Like I'm installing the glog now]:

```bash
PS D:\Users\installpkg\glog> cmake --build build --target install
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target glogbase
[ 30%] Built target glogbase
[ 34%] Built target glog
[ 38%] Built target glogtest
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target logging_unittest
[ 46%] Built target logging_unittest
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target logging_custom_prefix_unittest
[ 53%] Built target logging_custom_prefix_unittest
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target stl_logging_unittest
[ 61%] Built target stl_logging_unittest
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target demangle_unittest
[ 69%] Built target demangle_unittest
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target utilities_unittest
[ 76%] Built target utilities_unittest
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target cleanup_immediately_unittest
[ 84%] Built target cleanup_immediately_unittest
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target cleanup_with_absolute_prefix_unittest
[ 92%] Built target cleanup_with_absolute_prefix_unittest
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target cleanup_with_relative_prefix_unittest
[100%] Built target cleanup_with_relative_prefix_unittest
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Installing: D:/Users/installpkg/bin/lib/libglog.dll.a
-- Installing: D:/Users/installpkg/bin/bin/libglog.dll
-- Installing: D:/Users/installpkg/bin/include/glog/export.h
-- Installing: D:/Users/installpkg/bin/include/glog/logging.h
-- Installing: D:/Users/installpkg/bin/include/glog/raw_logging.h
-- Installing: D:/Users/installpkg/bin/include/glog/stl_logging.h
-- Installing: D:/Users/installpkg/bin/include/glog/vlog_is_on.h
-- Installing: D:/Users/installpkg/bin/include/glog/log_severity.h
-- Installing: D:/Users/installpkg/bin/include/glog/platform.h
-- Installing: D:/Users/installpkg/bin/lib/pkgconfig/libglog.pc
-- Installing: D:/Users/installpkg/bin/lib/cmake/glog/glog-modules.cmake
-- Installing: D:/Users/installpkg/bin/lib/cmake/glog/glog-config.cmake
-- Installing: D:/Users/installpkg/bin/lib/cmake/glog/glog-config-version.cmake
-- Installing: D:/Users/installpkg/bin/lib/cmake/glog/glog-targets.cmake
-- Installing: D:/Users/installpkg/bin/lib/cmake/glog/glog-targets-noconfig.cmake
```